# JS Change CSS line-height based on number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul list that is dynamically generated upon page load via JavaScript.
The code that is generated can be seen here (with irrelevant items removed):

```
<ul class="tweet_list"><li class="tweet_first tweet_odd"></li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
​ul.tweet_list li {
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

I'm trying to change the CSS `line-height` property based on the number of words in the Tweet (if over 9 words, I want the line height to change from 55px to 24px). Here is my JS:

```
$(function(){
    var $tweet = $(".tweet_first");
    var $numWords = $tweet.text().split(" ").length;
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 10)) {
        $tweet.css("line-height", "55px");
    }
    else {
        $tweet.css("line-height", "24px");
    }    
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the widget http://justpaste.it/twitter-widget

EDIT: My code isn't working. For some reason nothing I have above will change the line-height dynamically unless I go into my styles.css file and actually change the line height. HOW CAN I CALL IN MY JS THE `ul.tweet_list li` AND APPLY THE `line-height` property directly to it?

UPDATE: If someone can just tell me how to dynamically change the CSS portion, I can figure out how to detect the number of characters in the tweet. So, using Javascript, how can I change this:

```
​ul.tweet_list li {line-height: 55px; }​
```

to this:

​`ul.tweet_list li {line-height: 24px; }​`

UPDATE 2:
Code that calls the tweet:

```
jQuery(function($){
      $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
        join_text: "auto",
        username: "twitter_username",
        avatar_size: null,
        count: 1,
        auto_join_text_default: "",
        auto_join_text_ed: "",
        auto_join_text_ing: "",
        auto_join_text_reply: "",
        auto_join_text_url: "",
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
      });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see a question in here.  What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it shold be:

```
$(function(){
    var $tweet = $(".tweet_first");
    var $numWords = $tweet.text().split(" ").length;
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 10)) {
        $tweet.css({ "font-size": "55px", "line-height": "55px" });
    }
    else {
        $tweet.css({ "font-size": "24px", "line-height": "24px" });
    }    
});
```

UPDATE: Ok, maybe I've understand:

Taking a look to the documentation of the plugin you've used I see that you could bind an eventhandler like "loaded", that fires after the tweet is rendered. So you've to change your code with:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
    join_text: "auto",
    username: "twitter_username",
    avatar_size: null,
    count: 1,
    auto_join_text_default: "",
    auto_join_text_ed: "",
    auto_join_text_ing: "",
    auto_join_text_reply: "",
    auto_join_text_url: "",
    loading_text: "loading tweets..."
  }).bind("loaded", function() {
    var $tweet = $(".tweet_first"); // maybe using  $(this)  is better
    var $numWords = $tweet.text().split(" ").length;
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 10)) {
        $tweet.css({ "font-size": "55px", "line-height": "55px" });
    }
    else {
        $tweet.css({ "font-size": "24px", "line-height": "24px" });
    }
  });
});
```

Please try, is untested :)

Comment: the method to change the line-height is $("ul.tweet_list li").css("line-height", "55px"); but I suspect as, the others said, that your tweet isn't in the page on dom ready. are you loading it by an ajax call?

Comment: You are correct... the tweet isn't in the page on DOM ready. So how would I call what you put in the last comment?

Comment: You should inject your code in the function that loads the tweet, AFTER the corresponding LI is added to the page. Can you show us the code that calls the tweet?

Answer (score 0):

you are changing `font-size` in your code, that is probably the first problem so change:

```
    $tweet.css("font-size", ...
```

to

```
    $tweet.css("line-height", ...
```

okay well other than that your code looks okay, so I would try:

```
....
var $tweet = $(".tweet_first");
var $numWords = $tweet.text().split(" ").length;
alert("num of words: " + $numWords);  // make sure you are getting a value
alert("# of .tweet_first els: " + $tweet.length);  // make sure you have an element to change
...
```

Comment: Sorry, on my page it was correct but changed to font-size to test. Look again now :)

Comment: when I do the alert, it's only saying there is 1 word... ? There are more than 10 in the current tweet though. And in either case, it's not changing the line-height :(

Comment: @adamdehaven look @ my new edit, my guess is that the "tweet" is not there yet...

Comment: I believe you are correct... How can I make the JS runs AFTER the tweet is there?

Comment: UPDATE: Please look at the update at the bottom of the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @adamdehaven you are doing it correctly. you just need to get it to "fire" after the "tweet" populates, how is the "tweet" getting there? I take it you are not putting it there... I don't suppose I can actually view this page, this might go a lot quicker...

Comment: Is there a way to chat on here rather than posting all of the links?